# How do we bundle a react component to work with AMP Script

Tags: amp-html

I'm looking into amp-script and how it can be used on my site, currently have as react single page application with AMP Pages.

Wondering if I can use something like rect-loadable to code split some components producing a separate bundle for these components that can be used as the src for amp-script?

I am guessing these bundles would need to include react and what not to render correctly in the web worker?

Comment: Best to read the `amp-script` documentation. In our experiments, the limit is that all `javascript` code is local and complete (i.e it runs on `jsfiddle` with zero dependencies) and conforms to the `amp-script` size limitation.